# MOQ - Call same method twice with same parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to mock the `DataService` class for the `GetData` method.

```
Interface IProvider
{
   Response GetAccountInfo();
}

public class Provider:IProvider
{
      public Response GetAccountInfo()
      {
         Response resp = new Response();
         Response resp1 = new Response();
         DataService dataService = new DataService();
         resp = dataService.GetData("Girish" , "Advani" );
         resp1 = dataService.GetData("Pranav" , "Kawle" );

      }
}
```

I am getting value in resp object but the `resp1` object is null. I need the value of both objects. Could you please provide me solution for it?

Comment: The `Provider` class that you've included... is that your attempt at making a mock or is that the code that you're trying to test?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question properly, you need to call same method twice during on the mocked object.

You can use `SetupSequence` for this purpose.

e.g. Below, the test method calls the `GetNextStuff` method twice and returns one of the values alternatingly, each time it is called.

```
[Test]
public void MogMethodThatReturnsADifferentValueWhenCalledASecondTimeUsingSequences()
{
    Mock<ISomeService> _mockSomeService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
    _mockSomeService.SetupSequence(x => x.GetNextStuff())
            .Returns(new SomeStuff {Id = 1, Name = "Real"})
            .Returns((SomeStuff)null);
 
    Assert.IsNotNull(_mockSomeService.Object.GetNextStuff());
    Assert.IsNull(_mockSomeService.Object.GetNextStuff());
}
```

You can [refer this blog for more](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/c-setting-up-a-mocked-method-to-return-a-different-value-when-called-a-second-time-using-moq/) details.

Comment: This "GetAccountInfo" method needs to call only once, in above solution is not fit for requirement.

Comment: @VishalKedar - I assume that you want to test GetAccountInfo and you want to mock DataService.GetData calls.  Is it not the case ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want mock 1 interface like below one.

I think you can just mock your interface like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IProvider>();
var fakeResponse = new Response()
{
    //here set up the fake data
};
mock.Setup(x=>x.GetAccountInfo()).Returns(fakeResponse);
```

Comment: It's not working I am getting value in resp object but not in resp1, need values in both objects resp and resp1.

Comment: if you want to mock the whole IProvider interface then you can decide what would be the result of the `GetAccountInfo` method. You don't care what is the implementation of the Provider class.

Comment: Maybe better say what thing you want to test?